# Flask session is not persisting react

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, session, flask-session

I am making a flask + react website and I want to use session, But the session does not persist between requests.

I know it is caused because of CORS and I already solved that kind of problem in a flask +  react native project but here it does not work.

My flask initialization is like so:

```
# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='front-app/build', static_url_path='')
#secret key
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'secret'

# configure cors
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

app.config.update(
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True,
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='Lax',
)

# make session permanent
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True

# Ensure responses aren't cached
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers['Strict-Transport-Security'] = 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
    response.headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = 'nosniff'
    response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
    response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = '1; mode=block'
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response
```

The route:

```
@app.route("/api", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@cross_origin()
def index():
if request.method == "GET":
        # create game arr
        print(session.get("wo")) # prints None every time
        session["wo"] = 1
        
        wordsArr = session.get("wordsArr")
        today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        if wordsArr is None or session.get("date") != today:
            wordsArr = [[] for x in range(6)]
            for i in range(6):
                for k in range(5):
                    wordsArr[i].append({"letter": "", "color": ""})
            session["date"] = today
        
        selectedWord, wordCount = HelpFunc.generate_word(db, conn)
        
        return json.dumps({"wordsArr": wordsArr, "selectedWord": selectedWord, "wordCount": wordCount})
```

The request from react:

```
export const getData = async () => {
const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.32:5000/api', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})

if (response.ok) {
    const result = await response.json()
    return result
}

const errMessage = await response.text()
throw new Error(errMessage)
```

}